# Non understood template and accessibility behavior

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

In any case, `A::Stuff` is `protected`, so why inheriting from `A` and forcing its members' accessibility to `protected` resulting in an error ?

```cpp
class A {
   protected:
    template <typename T>
    static void Stuff() {
        T::template Stuff<T>();
    }
};

class B : protected A {
   public:
    void something() { A::Stuff<B>(); }

    // I have these two, inelegant workarounds:
    // using A::Stuff;    // KO: This is wrong, it changes the accessibility of Stuff.
    // class B : public A // KO: Accessibility changed.
    // friend A;          // OK: This seems fine.
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.something();
}
```

Code available at: https://godbolt.org/z/r1Ya3rzsK

Assuming the classes `A` and `B` as defined above clang and gcc will give you something like that:

```
'Stuff' is a protected member of 'A'
        T::template Stuff<T>();
```

I give a workaround in the comment and more are welcome as long as the members' accessibility is not changed.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.access.base#5.3

Comment: You cannot access protected sections of another class. If `A` had a protected member  `a`, that member would be visible from `B` instances, but not as `A::a` but as `B::a` so to speak. You have plenty of documentation regarding this. On the other hand, I understand you cannot simply call `Stuff();` from `B`, `Stuff()` being a local, maybe static, `B` method, can you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `A::Stuff<B>()` will call `T::Stuff<T>()` with `T=B` aka `B::Stuff<B>()`. B doesn't have a `Stuff` function, so it will try falling back to `A::Stuff` which is invalid, as you made the inheritance protected. (btw if it was valid, because the inheritance was public that would lead to an infinite recursion).

I think you don't want an infinite recursion here. If you want `Stuff<B>` to be valid add a `Stuff` function to B.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
   protected:
    template <typename T>
    static void Stuff() {
        std::cout<<"called A\n";
        T::template Stuff<T>();
    }
};

class B : protected A {
   public:
    void something() { A::Stuff<B>(); }

    template <typename T>
    static void Stuff() {
        std::cout<<"called B\n";
        //...
    }
    // I have these two, inelegant workarounds:
    // using A::Stuff;    // KO: This is wrong, it changes the visibility of Stuff.
    // class B : public A // KO: Visibility changed.
    // friend A;          // OK: This seems fine.
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.something();
}
```